# Auto Position and Scale Embed iFrame

Tags: html, css, canvas

Hello I'm trying to make a very simple website consisting of a background image and a floating youtube video. My problem is that I need the youtube video to be on a specific place and resize to fill that determined space regardless of resolution or browser window.

The video needs to go in the dark area middle left; I'm not too sure what to do I haven't coded in a while. I've got the background to resize adequetly but other than that. I've tried to follow these guides.

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/

I would appreciate any help. You can find the image here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkYos.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Put the iframe into a div and position it absolute where you want

http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/

make sure you set the z-index to a higher positive value to make it stay "on top"

See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=absolute+position+div

Comment: That doesnt work still moves around with window resizing and different resolutions render the video out of the designated spot.